# What's the Ruby equivalent of C ?: operator?

Tags: ruby

C has short conditional branch operator.

```
int a = 1 < 2 ? 3 : 4;
```

What's the equivalent in Ruby?

Comment: It's the same, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = true  ? 'a' : 'b' #=> "a"
b = false ? 'a' : 'b' #=> "b"
```

Answer (score 4):

Ruby too have ternary operator, you can do it in the same way.

```
a = 1 < 2 ? 3 : 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a whole `if` statement since it is also an expression:

```
a = if 1 < 2 then 3 else 4 end
```

or even:

```
a = if 1 < 2
      3
    else
      4
    end
```

Comment: Even though I use the ternary operator fairly often, the if-then-else one-liner should be preferred, since its much more readable, exspecially if you have complex conditions or the like.